# Related list not working inside PageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce

I have the following code:

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!projectList}" var="c" >

    <apex:column headerValue="Title" headerClass="ct">
        <apex:outputLink value="/{!c.id}"><apex:outputText value="{!c.Project_Title__c}" /></apex:outputLink>  
    </apex:column>

    <apex:column headerValue="End Date" value="{!c.Project_End_Date__c}" headerClass="ct"/>

    <apex:column headerValue="Open Cases" value="{!c.Open_Cases_TEXT__c}" headerClass="ct"/>

    <apex:column headerValue="Cases" headerClass="ct" id="caseCol" rendered="true">
        <apex:relatedList subject="{!c.Id}" list="Cases__r"/>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

My problem is the above code works fine, however it only returns the first cases relatedList, and doesn't seem to iterate with the pageBlockTable rows to the next project. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create a standard list controllers. 
In the top of your visualforce page use something similar to this. The most important part is the "recordSetVar" that will give you a list related to your standard controller.

```
 <apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts" tabstyle="account" sidebar="false">
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a">
    <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Hey Viasur, I am using recordSetVar. My projects display fine as a record set, but the related lists for projects just display the first projects cases.

Comment: Hey Sam, would be good to have the full code. Can you please show us the all code for that page? I assume that you are using a standard controller with no extensions? If you have extensions we probably need to have that Apex as well.